# Web App not loading in my cordova app in certain Wifi

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap

I have a web app hosted in a specific URL www.MYWEBAPP.com and I have created a Cordova app to load it on my Android Phone and have access to certain hardware features. This Cordova app only loads the view of my URL (www.MYWEBAPP.com).

Here comes the weird part. I have tried it on my Android with my mobile data and it works fine, I have tried it on my Android connected to my wifi and it also works fine, but whenever I try it on my Android connected to my work's Wifi it doesn't work, the screen stays white and doesn't show anything. However, if I close my Cordova app and try in the browser of my phone (Google Chrome app) introducing directly my URL (www.MYWEBAPP.com) it works perfectly even connected to my work's Wifi.

[Here is a screenshot of my Cordova app permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWtTs.png)
[image]

Any ideas on why this might be happening or what is my work's Wifi blocking that makes my app not load my URL?

Comment: hi, how are you loading the view ? using any frames?..

Comment: Assuming no workplace internet filters, VPNs, etc.?